# twelvefold way in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Background: I have a beginner level understanding in Probability.
I am confused how the basics of twelvefold way relates to binomial distribution (from basic counting to probability). Hence, the motivation of the following question.

For the $n$ boxes  and $m$ balls, both distinguishable and at most one ball can go into the box the possibility is $P(n,m)$ is for the case where $n>m$, correct? what if $n\leq m$? generally, textbooks follow the path that first box can be filled in $n$ ways, second box in $n-1$ ways and not first object can go to $m$ boxes, second boxes can go to to $m-1$ boxes.. how to analyse then? Also, how are the cases of replacement addressed in the twelvefold way i.e. arranged w/o replacement or with replacement?

Comment: Whar have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: "*at most one ball can go into a box*" and you have more balls than boxes?  Pigeon-hole principle suggests that to be impossible.  If you have the same number of balls as boxes and one ball per box, that is $n!$.  The same argument applies for deriving the result.

Comment: As for with without replacement vs with replacement in general problems, that is akin to not allowing more than one ball per box vs allowing however many balls in a box, and that is described in the usual way in twelvefoldway by talking about injective functions vs functions in general.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much sir for the clarification.. I read this statement in a book, "If only r positions are to be filled with objects selected from n different objects, r ≤ n, then the number of possible ordered arrangements is nPr." I am confused to what segment of the twelve cells this statement maps to? Is it the function always N->K (n,k belongs to same set let's say A), such that there are n boxes and out of objects we are choosing only r objects (a subset of N) and arranging them?

Comment: @Saad thank you sir, I will try to inculcate the same.